# Why does the function always return zero elapsed time?

Tags: c++, benchmarking

I am writing an Android application using Java. Also I am using jni interface to call native function.
For example:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_app_Native_test(JNIEnv *env, jobject object)
{
   steady_clock::time_point begin = steady_clock::now();
   int lenght = 500000000;
   int * arr1 = new int[lenght];
   for(int i = 0; i < lenght; i++)
   {
       *(arr1+i) = i+1;
   }
   matrix<int, 100> matrix1(arr1, lenght);
   steady_clock::time_point end = steady_clock::now();
   return duration_cast<microseconds>(end-begin).count();
}
```

This function measures how long it takes to create an array(arr1) and an object(matrix1). The problem is that the function always returns 0. In fact, this cannot be. If you add a value to the time that depends on the object, then everything will work as it should. That is:

```
return duration_cast<microseconds>(end-begin).count()+matrix1(1, 1);
//matrix1(1, 1) = 1
```

What should I do in this case if I don't want to constantly add a value dependent on the object?

Comment: `int lenght = 5000000000;` is a scary array size for an Android device.  How much memory does your device have?

Comment: 12 gigabytes of RAM, always free about 8-7 gigabytes

Comment: Important: the length of the array is not 5 billion, but 500 million.

Comment: And what is the resolution of `steady_clock`?

Comment: are you using compiler optimisations? Your code doesn't appear to have any side effects (please show a [mre]) so the compiler can just delete all of it resulting in a zero runtime

Comment: It’s highly suspicious to use `int` for time measurement. You should always use `long`. Besides that, it’s not surprising if an optimizing compiler eliminates calculations when you don’t use the result.

Comment: NB Length, not lenght.

Comment: What is the definition of `matrix`, and how certain are you that the compiler has not optimized away all of your code?

Comment: Updated tags as this is a plain c++ benchmarking question. No JNI or Java involved.

Answer (score 2):

I took your code and added a dummy definition of `matrix` that just stores the provided pointer and total length:

```
template <class T, size_t width>
struct matrix {
    matrix(T* ptr, size_t len) : ptr(ptr), len(len) {}
    T* ptr;
    size_t len;
 };
```

Clang removed *all* of the code between your measurements: ([Compiler explorer link](https://godbolt.org/z/xqEG4j8cj))

```
Java_com_app_Native_test():          # @Java_com_app_Native_test()
        push    rbx
        call    std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock::now()@PLT
        mov     rbx, rax
        call    std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock::now()@PLT
// function epilogue follows
```

If you actually make use of the `matrix` instance somehow, the compiler is forced to go through the full initialization process. This is a very common gotcha in benchmarking and is the reason why you should avoid rolling it yourself. See for example the section [Preventing optimization](https://github.com/google/benchmark/blob/main/docs/user_guide.md#preventing-optimization) in the Google Benchmark documentation. (and switch to that for benchmarking stuff in the future)